# None of the DVDs can be read

Tags: vlc, dvd

It does not matter what kind of DVD I try to play on either my DVD-ROM or my DVD-R/RW I get the same error message from VLC media player.

I have tried all disc device options.  This is the error message:

```
Playback failure:
DVDRead could not open the disc "/dev/dvd".
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'dvd:///dev/dvd'. Check the log for details.
```

Comment: Can you provide the log?

Comment: Sounds like the /dev/dvd symbolic link is not correctly set up.  Consider finding out the device name of the drive, and tell that to vlc instead.

Comment: Show us the output of these 2 commands. mount|grep ^'/dev' sudo lshw -C disk

Answer (score 1):

Do you have all the codecs installed?

If not add the medibuntu repository. Open a terminal and paste the following

```
sudo -E wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list && sudo apt-get --quiet update && sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring && sudo apt-get --quiet update
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libdvdcss2
```

Otherwise it might be a hardware problem. Hopefully someone else can step in and assist. Good luck.